# Как перебрать массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Мне нужно перебрать массив из двух значений, чтобы на выходе получить все значения между ними.
Например: `['10-07-2018', '18-07-2018']` = > `['11-07-2018', '12-07-2018', '13-07-2018', '14-07-2018', '15-07-2018', '16-07-2018', '17-07-2018']`
Каким методом так можно сделать? + мне нужно будет проверять когда закончится месяц, чтобы переходить на следующий.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var arr = ['10-07-2018', '18-07-2018'];
  
  
  
  console.log(arr);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: используй moment.js. Очень удобно

Comment: а если без плагинов? много кода писать? или это 3-5 проверок и все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `javascript` с [таким форматом](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) работать не получиться:

> "DD-MM-YYYY" формат вернет `undefined`. Некоторые браузеры будут пытаться прочитать данный формат, но некоторые просто вернут `NaN`

Используйте международный формат, универсальное решение:

```js
const getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
    currentDate = startDate,
    addDays = function(days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      return date;
    };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = `${currentDate.getMonth() +
      1}-${currentDate.getDate()}-${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

let datesArray = ["2018-07-10", "2018-07-18"];
datesArray = [...getDates(new Date(datesArray[0]), new Date(datesArray[1]))];
console.log(datesArray);
```

В любом случае вы потом можете элементы массива после того, как его получили, перевести в любой другой формат.

### Все таки нашел способ работать с "DD-MM-YYYY" форматом:

```js
const getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
    currentDate = startDate,
    addDays = function(days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      return date;
    };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    let formatedDate = `${('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2)}-${('0' + (currentDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)}-${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;
    dates.push(formatedDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

let dateArray = ["07-07-2018", "11-07-2018"];
dateArray = [
  ...getDates(
    new Date(dateArray[0].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")),
    new Date(dateArray[1].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))
  )
];
console.log(dateArray);
```

Работает отлично!

Comment: то есть мне придется сначала перевести в нужный формат для изменения массива, а потом обратно? Не слишком сложный код для такой задачи?

Comment: @max исторически так сложилось, что вы предлагаете?

Comment: `function reverseDate(arrDate) {
                        var newArrDate = arrDate.split(",").reverse().join("");
                        console.log(newArrDate);
                    }
                    reverseDate(arrDate);` типа такого?

Comment: @max ну вот видите у вас есть способ решения данной задачи

Comment: @max посмотри обновленный ответ, можешь работать с нужным форматом

Comment: из-за чего у меня может быть такая ошибка? `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. Я пишу в `es5`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79782/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and-max).

Comment: @max в чат зайди

Comment: Второй вариант не работает все таки

Comment: @max честно не знаю, почему для `es5` `replace` не срабатывает